# How to make a Runkeeper-like timeline post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm a little curious about what happens when the app "Runkeeper" publishes on one's timeline. Is it the Open Graph? I've been looking a bit but found nothing that causes it to get the same look as their publications. Is there anyone here who knows of a guide or anything else that you can follow?

The purpose of the question was to find out how it works, as I've searched around but found nothing similar. I also want to find a guide that can help me. I think others will find an answer helpful in the future.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) allows actions categorized in:

- Music
- Movies and Television
- Books
- Fitness
- General

Runkeeper uses the [fitness actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness/).

> ### Bike, Walk, Run
>
> For developers building fitness apps, Facebook provides common
> fitness.bikes, fitness.walks and fitness.runs actions.
>
> These actions support the following fitness common objects:
>
> - The course object. You run, bike or walk a course.
> - The unit object. Fitness common objects can reference a developer defined fitness unit
>   of measure (e.g. NikeFuel).

#### Example

[image: Example]

Comment: Oh, never knew that. I'll start checking it out asap! Cheers!

Comment: specifically you add ActivityDataPoint items on the coarse part of an activity